# Prisma migrate drops custom table partitions

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm using Prisma ORM for PostgreSQL and trying to partition a couple of my tables so I need modifying my SQL files manually. I used `prisma migrate dev --create-only`, created partitions tables then ran `prisma migrate dev` (as [this page](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations) suggests).

It successfully applies my changes along its own, however after first migration applied the prisma prompts for another migration in which it tries to delete all created tables:

```
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "omnichannel", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"

Applying migration `20220518160933_init`

The following migration(s) have been applied:

migrations/
  └─ 20220518160933_init/
    └─ migration.sql
√ Enter a name for the new migration: ... init2
```

It seems like the prisma tries to revert manually created tables, Is there any way to prevent this?